# My Sql WorkBench - wrong number of columns in target DB

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

We are using MySQL Workbench 6.2 to migrate data.  Our source table and destination table have different numbers of columns.  Say, the source table has 16 and destination table has 18.

When we migrate, Workbench says

> Error wrong number of columns in target DB.

Do the source and destination table columns numbers to be same?  Or is there some way to tell Workbench default or derived values for the destination table columns?

Comment: Can you tell us the *detailed* steps of what you're doing with Workbench, or link the tutorial you're following?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.We are using migration wizard feature in workbench. we are not using any query.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are doing a `SELECT INTO` query like this in your migrate script/step, that depends on the number of columns in the database rather than the actual column names.

```
SELECT *
INTO newtable [IN externaldb]
FROM table1;
```

Or

```
insert into items_ver
select * from items where item_id=2;
```

Somewhere along the line, your databases have changed in the number of rows available, so you cant do either of those

You can either specicy the columns like this:

```
insert into items_ver(column1, column2, column3)
select column1, column2, column3 from items where item_id=2;
```

Or add the 2 missing columns from the one database into the other, and ensure that they all match up.

Comment: Thanks Octopi for your reply.We are using migration wizard option in workbench. we are not using any query

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL Workbench migration wizard (or schema transfer wizard) there is no way to do that. All columns in source and target databases must match.